# Floating images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating website with some product images list for my client. In one line i can have only 3 product images and my employer wants to center line of images if it's not full (less than 3 objects).
Of course the easiest way is to implement another class for images in "incomplete" line, but i have to provide website managment to my employer without any programming after all of that, so this solution is not for me ;)

Here is [codepen](http://codepen.io/jakub_stefko/pen/NAEgkA) with what i did, but i am still missing something.

I would really appreciate if you would straighten up my JS.

I am also quite afraid about this line:

```
$(document).ready(function()
```

I heard, that it is not the safest way to work with photos in JS, becouse photos can load after that line and it could get messy.

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

will look like:

```
<a href="some_big_image_in_gallery_overlay.jpg" class="gal">
  <img src="some_small_image_on_website.jpg">
</a>
```

Hope that you will help me clear my concerns about img loading and bugged JS code :)

Comment: u have to include jquery library in JS section settings=>Add external javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be sufficient, to just align the boxes with CSS:

```
.fruits {
  text-align: center;
}
.miniImgBox {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Explained: remove the `float` from your image boxes and set their display to `inline-block`. This way, you can just apply the `text-align: center` rule to the container.

Comment: thanks for answer, i am overreacting sometimes :/ in few minutes your answer will be accepted as first correct (sorry Phil)

Comment: Right, that's the main thing! Anyway, you have my upvote!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way, is to use `display: inline-block;` and `text-align: center`.
Try this:

```
.fruits {
    text-align: center;
}
.miniImgBox
{
    width: 370px;
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 1px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```